# rails DateTime.parse for DateTime posting from client from a jquery time picker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetimepicker

after upgrading to Rails 3.2 and Ruby 1.9.3 
my forms which contains a jquery date picker, stopped working..

in my params is see the date:

```
"created_at"=>"03/22/2013 05:28 am"
```

but if i try to parse it like so:

```
DateTime.parse(params[:entry]["created_at"])
```

then it returns this error:

> *** ArgumentError Exception: invalid date

how can i parse this kind of datetime and then turn it into UTC?

thanks

Comment: what do you want to extract by parsing date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope you are looking for the following.

```
 DateTime.strptime(params[:entry]["created_at"], '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %P')
```

This will output the following result

```
Fri, 22 Mar 2013 05:28:00 +0000
```

Comment: OK i think i should of explained my problem more. because now i see i cant really solve my problem like that. i want to call @entry.update_attributes(params[:entry]) on my update action in the controller. but what happens is that after i call it, created_at column becomes null. so i guessed its because activeRecord isn't parsing my string to a date correctly.. any advice?